# In Automator, how to get the folder contents after a "Run Shell Script" action

Tags: automator

I have an Automator application where I'd like to drag a folder onto it and have it create a duplicate (sibling) of that folder with the duplicate's files renamed. For example, starting with the following:

```
root
 +--svgs
     |--icons_a.svg
     +--icons_b.svg
```

When dragging the `svgs` directory onto the application, I would like to end up with the following:

```
root
 |--svgs
 |   |--icons_a.svg
 |   +--icons_b.svg
 +--renamed-svgs
     |--a.svg
     +--b.svg
```

I've tried the following:
[image]

But it throws the following:

[image]

Not sure how to debug the error, but how can I get the first "Run Shell Script" action to return either the "renamed-svgs" folder or that folder's contents?

Or is there a better way to do this whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

It is generally advisable to enclose a variable in double quotes.

Use the `echo` command to return the "**renamed-svgs**" folder

```
rm -rf "$@"/../renamed-svgs
cp -rf "$@"/ "$@"/../renamed-svgs
echo "$@"/../renamed-svgs/
```

---

Or use the `find` command to return files whose name start with **icons_**

```
rm -rf "$@"/../renamed-svgs
cp -rf "$@"/ "$@"/../renamed-svgs
find "$@/../renamed-svgs/" -type f -maxdepth 1 -iname 'icons_*' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is exactly what will happen for bash scripts if the application it is communicating with isn't a *Running Application* when it's interacted with. As for a better way to perform the task, no, automator is awesome.

- I know, not a full answer, but I cannot comment and my statement is true.